# What methods fire when coming back from a fragment where using Navigation Components?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have a single activity named MainActivity which holds the `FirstFragment`. Using Navigation Components I already set that the single fragment that can be opened from `FirstFragment` is `SecondFragment`. I have also enabled back button to be able to navigate back from `SecondFragment` to the `FirstFragment`. The problem is when I get back to the `FirstFragment`, `onStart()` method is **not** triggered. What methods fire in this case? How to know when I get back from `SecondFragment` to `FirstFragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCreateView() method of the first fragment is called whenever you press the back button from the second fragment if you are doing this right. The layout of this fragment is inflated in onCreateView() method. So that you will see first fragment screen.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `onCreateView()` is called and now I can put my logic inside. Thank you.